# Using Custom Links to Add a Product to the Cart without being direct to cart.php

Tags: button, hyperlink, product, cart, bigcommerce

Big Commerce doesn't have native integration to allow a flat fee added to a total, so in place of that I wanted to add an extra button to my product page that would add the flat rate product to the cart using the product id. I found that I could do this (https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/How-can-I-add-a-product-to-the-cart-with-a-link?language=en_US#add-to-cart), I used this link: `<a href="/cart.php?action=add&sku=5016" class="button button--green coa-btn">Add Certificate of Analysis (+$25)</a>` to add the product to the cart, however ideally I would like to stay on that product page, not be redirected to the cart page.
Any suggestions on how to fix/work around this?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can add products using the Storefront Cart API, or a fetch request to the Add to cart URL. See https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/add-to-cart-urls#adding-multiple-products
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/carts

The other option is to use the stencil-utils itemAdd function (utils.api.cart.itemAdd) https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/stencil-utils-api-reference#cart-api

However, in your case, it may be simpler to add the certificate as a product option. Or does this route not work for you?

Edit: script to run to add a product and not go anywhere:

```
$('button#addToCart').on('click', () =>
  $.get('/cart.php?action=add&sku=5016')
    .done((data, status) => {
    // do something here if you want
    console.log(`first item complete with status ${status}`);
}));
```

Comment: Hey Matt, I appreciate the info. Unfortunately, for our case the certificate was an option, but it should be a one time add on, when a customer would buy the product in a quantity of more than one, the customer would be charged that many times for a certificate (ex: buy 3, get charged 3 times for cert. when it should only ever be once). In regards to the Storefront Cart API, are there any tutorials or how to implement? Not as familiar with API coding, can't find any extra help on BC

Comment: @alexispsc The first link I posted there should have everything you need. Just add a button and a script that runs the fetch/get. I've edited my comment to pare down the script to what you need.